# Sort array of objects depending on another array values Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays:
**First array :**

```
SelectedRows= 
[
   {
      "NR":"4",
      "KUNNR":"9?AMT132",
      "NAME":" AUTO TOURING HANDELS GES.M.B.H.",
      "LATLON":[
         15.4114217,
         47.0664085
      ],
      "LIN":"LIN097"
   },
   {
      "NR":"3",
      "KUNNR":"9Z?CH005",
      "NAME":" Z?CHNER ERDBAU U TRANSPORT GMBH",
      "LATLON":[
         13.4216536,
         47.3747925
      ],
      "LIN":"LIN099"
   },
   {
      "NR":"2",
      "KUNNR":"9SMTA001",
      "NAME":" SMT AUTOTEILE",
      "LATLON":[
         13.2277803,
         47.9525892
      ],
      "LIN":"LIN0102"
   },
   {
      "NR":"1",
      "KUNNR":"9REIT051",
      "NAME":" W.REITINGER GMBH",
      "LATLON":[
         14.4017044,
         48.2213305
      ],
      "LIN":"LIN0103"
   }
]
```

**Second array is**

```
LOCATIONS =
[
   [
      15.4114217,
      47.0664085
   ],
   [
      14.4017044,
      48.2213305
   ],
   [
      13.2277803,
      47.9525892
   ],
   [
      13.4216536,
      47.3747925
   ]
]
```

I need to sort the first array (SelectedRows) on matching values from SelectedRows.LATLON on the second array(LOCATIONS)

I tried to do:

```
var Output= LOCATIONS.filter(function(obj) { 
            return SelectedRows.LATLON.indexOf(obj) == -1; 
        });
```

but it did not work.
SO if anyone can give me an advice I will be so gratefull.
Sorry for my bad english, to get the idea I am posting the expected output:

**Expected output :**

```
Output=[
{
    "NR":"4",
    "KUNNR":"9?AMT132",
    "NAME":" AUTO TOURING HANDELS GES.M.B.H.",
    "LATLON":[
        15.4114217,
        47.0664085
    ],
    "LIN":"LIN097"
},
{
    "NR":"1",
    "KUNNR":"9REIT051",
    "NAME":" W.REITINGER GMBH",
    "LATLON":[
        14.4017044,
        48.2213305
    ],
    "LIN":"LIN0103"
},
{
    "NR":"2",
    "KUNNR":"9SMTA001",
    "NAME":" SMT AUTOTEILE",
    "LATLON":[
        13.2277803,
        47.9525892
    ],
    "LIN":"LIN0102"
},
{
    "NR":"3",
    "KUNNR":"9Z?CH005",
    "NAME":" Z?CHNER ERDBAU U TRANSPORT GMBH",
    "LATLON":[
        13.4216536,
        47.3747925
    ],
    "LIN":"LIN099"
}]
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: `I tried a lot` show how you tried at all

Comment: Sorry I've dited the post.

Comment: your problem is you don't understand what filter returns, you don't need to filter, you meed to map - also `locations` isn't the same as `LOCATIONS` and `SelectedRows` is an Array, so ot won't have a `LATLON` property

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explain. It helps a lot. Since I am in my appartment suffering of this cov, and got so tired of thinking I missed the right way of thinking. Best regards.

Comment: On a unrelated note, you should check your encoding. "Z?chner Erdbau" probably should be "Zöchner Erdbau" with the German Umlaut `ö`.

Comment: @Mushroomator
Thanks for  the advice but yes the encoding is already fine in FE. but now I am working on my personal pc which doesn't have the Deutsch Support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you should be doing is to [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) `LOCATIONS`

in the map you [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) the appropriate item in `SelectedRows` ...

be aware that `[1,2] !== [1,2]` so you can't compare arrays in your find, since you'll never find anything - either compare each element of the arrays, or, in this case, you could check if `array1.join() === array2.join()`

```js
const SelectedRows = [ { "NR":"4", "KUNNR":"9?AMT132", "NAME":" AUTO TOURING HANDELS GES.M.B.H.", "LATLON":[ 15.4114217, 47.0664085 ], "LIN":"LIN097" }, { "NR":"3", "KUNNR":"9Z?CH005", "NAME":" Z?CHNER ERDBAU U TRANSPORT GMBH", "LATLON":[ 13.4216536, 47.3747925 ], "LIN":"LIN099" }, { "NR":"2", "KUNNR":"9SMTA001", "NAME":" SMT AUTOTEILE", "LATLON":[ 13.2277803, 47.9525892 ], "LIN":"LIN0102" }, { "NR":"1", "KUNNR":"9REIT051", "NAME":" W.REITINGER GMBH", "LATLON":[ 14.4017044, 48.2213305 ], "LIN":"LIN0103" } ], LOCATIONS = [ [ 15.4114217, 47.0664085 ], [ 14.4017044, 48.2213305 ], [ 13.2277803, 47.9525892 ], [ 13.4216536, 47.3747925 ] ] 

const output =  LOCATIONS.map(
  a=>SelectedRows.find(({LATLON}) => LATLON.join() === a.join())
);

console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important; top:0; }
.as-console-row::after { display:none !important; }
```

Although, for truly readable code

```js
const SelectedRows = [ { "NR":"4", "KUNNR":"9?AMT132", "NAME":" AUTO TOURING HANDELS GES.M.B.H.", "LATLON":[ 15.4114217, 47.0664085 ], "LIN":"LIN097" }, { "NR":"3", "KUNNR":"9Z?CH005", "NAME":" Z?CHNER ERDBAU U TRANSPORT GMBH", "LATLON":[ 13.4216536, 47.3747925 ], "LIN":"LIN099" }, { "NR":"2", "KUNNR":"9SMTA001", "NAME":" SMT AUTOTEILE", "LATLON":[ 13.2277803, 47.9525892 ], "LIN":"LIN0102" }, { "NR":"1", "KUNNR":"9REIT051", "NAME":" W.REITINGER GMBH", "LATLON":[ 14.4017044, 48.2213305 ], "LIN":"LIN0103" } ], LOCATIONS = [ [ 15.4114217, 47.0664085 ], [ 14.4017044, 48.2213305 ], [ 13.2277803, 47.9525892 ], [ 13.4216536, 47.3747925 ] ] 

const output = LOCATIONS.map(([tgtLat, tgtLon]) =>
  SelectedRows.find(
    ({ LATLON: [lat, lon] }) => tgtLat === lat && tgtLon === lon
  )
);

console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100%!important; top:0; }
.as-console-row::after { display:none !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way (at least asymptotically) to do this in `O(n)` time given you have `n` elements both in `selectedRows` and `locations` is the following.

1. Loop over locations which is the *correct* order and map the location values to the index they are (supposed to be) at.
   You cannot use the array as such for this as arrays cannot be compared using `Object.is()` which `Map` uses internally. So you could for example use a concatenated string here. There may be better/ cleaner options but this is simple and does the job.  This will take `O(n)`.

The map then will look like this:

```
Map(4) {
  '15.4114217,47.0664085' => 0,
  '14.4017044,48.2213305' => 1,
  '13.2277803,47.9525892' => 2,
  '13.4216536,47.3747925' => 3
}
```

2. Loop through the `selectedRows` and for each object determine it's key which is again the location concatenated and using that key get the index the object is supposed to be at in `O(1)`. If the current index and the target index match everything is fine. If not, we need to swap the object to the target index which is obviously done in `O(1)`. This will in total also take `O(n)`.

Done. Combined the steps will take `O(n)` time and it will therefore be a asymptotically optimal algorithm.

```js
const selectedRows = 
[
   {
      "NR":"4",
      "KUNNR":"9?AMT132",
      "NAME":" AUTO TOURING HANDELS GES.M.B.H.",
      "LATLON":[
         15.4114217,
         47.0664085
      ],
      "LIN":"LIN097"
   },
   {
      "NR":"3",
      "KUNNR":"9Z?CH005",
      "NAME":" Z?CHNER ERDBAU U TRANSPORT GMBH",
      "LATLON":[
         13.4216536,
         47.3747925
      ],
      "LIN":"LIN099"
   },
   {
      "NR":"2",
      "KUNNR":"9SMTA001",
      "NAME":" SMT AUTOTEILE",
      "LATLON":[
         13.2277803,
         47.9525892
      ],
      "LIN":"LIN0102"
   },
   {
      "NR":"1",
      "KUNNR":"9REIT051",
      "NAME":" W.REITINGER GMBH",
      "LATLON":[
         14.4017044,
         48.2213305
      ],
      "LIN":"LIN0103"
   }
]

const locations =
[
   [
      15.4114217,
      47.0664085
   ],
   [
      14.4017044,
      48.2213305
   ],
   [
      13.2277803,
      47.9525892
   ],
   [
      13.4216536,
      47.3747925
   ]
]

console.log("Previous", selectedRows);

const indexMap = new Map();

// Map values to indices
locations.forEach((loc, idx) => indexMap.set(`${loc[0]},${loc[1]}`, idx));

// put each object to the correct position
selectedRows.forEach((row , i) => {
    // concatenate lookup key
    const key = `${row.LATLON[0]},${row.LATLON[1]}`;
    // check if value is actually in map => should always be the case (assumption: locations and showLocation contain the same locations)
    if(indexMap.has(key)){
        const targetIndex = indexMap.get(key);
        // check if the object is at the right position
        if(!targetIndex === i){
            // position is wrong => swap positions
            const temp = selectedRows[i];
            selectedRows[i] = selectedRows[targetIndex];
            selectedRows[targetIndex] = temp;
        }
    }
})

console.log("After", selectedRows);
```

> Note: you would need to make sure that the two variables `locations` and `selectedRows` actually contain the same locations and are of equal length.

Answer (score 1):

Following code is a bit dirty, but it works:

```
LOCATIONS_ORDER = LOCATIONS.map(e => `${e[0]};${e[1]}`);
SelectedRows.forEach(e => e.index = LOCATIONS_ORDER.indexOf(`${e.LATLON[0]};${e.LATLON[1]}`));

SelectedRows.sort((a,b) => a.index-b.index);

console.log(SelectedRows);
```

Comment: `.sort` ... why would you need to `sort` since `LOCATIONS` is in the required order?

Comment: I'm sorting "SelectedRows" not "LOCATIONS"

Comment: indeed - but why are you sorting anything?